# Help on Payment functionlity

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iPhone development.

I have a application in which i need to charge .50 USD for each mail the user sends…i have googled for store-kit framework and found nothing useful since i am not sure how to proceed with…

Can you people explain me how can i accomplish that.

Any help can be much appreciated…( it can be link or references or please explain me bit more about how can i go with implementing the above things please)

Thanks for stopping by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the link to Apple's in-app purchasing system:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Specifically, the page on how to make a purchase:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW3

Answer (score 0):

Most applications which depend on using real money will do bulk buys of credits using the in-app purchase mechanism. For instance, have a $1 "2 mail" in application purchase.

The apple documentation covers how to use the in-app purchase mechanism.